# Pie highcharts does not get rendered

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to create a simple pie chart. But it does not seems to be rendered. I am trying with the codes at the below link. 
Seems to be have some problem with the tooltip- pointFormat and plotOptions- format codes. It is the bold tag that is causing the problem.
Can anyone advise me? Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/

```
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: '#000000',
                connectorColor: '#000000',
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That example works for me. Do you not get anything rendered ? What browser are you using ?

Comment: What is incorrect with this example?

Comment: @Sebastian nothing is incorrect with the codes. Just that the chart doesn't get rendered if it has bold tag inside the codes. I am using Primefaces 3.5. Does that matters?

Comment: @SteveP yes, nothing get rendered. it only get rendered if i removed the bold tag. Tried with IE 9, firefox and Chrome. Same case for 3 browsers.

Comment: @bittersour I'm still not clear what your problem is.  If I have bold tags or out in that example it still works.  Can you create a fiddle that illustrates the problem (i.e. where the chart does not render)?

Comment: @Babara I meant, if the code contains bold tag, the chart doesn't get rendered at all. Its blank. I am not too sure if Primefaces 3.5 will affect this?

Comment: But it looks like problem with primefaces which interprets code / html in other way.

Comment: @SebastianBochan That's what I am thinking too. Any way to go around it?

Comment: Honestly I'm not familiar with primefaces.

Comment: @SebastianBochan I see. I will try to do some more googling and see if I can get anything. (: